# redefinition token type in parser

Tags: antlr4

Need to implement syntax highlighting for COS aka [MUMPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MUMPS)
for the language of a possible design of the form

```
new (new,set,kill)
set kill=new
```

where: 'new' and 'set' are commands, and also variable

```
grammar cos;

Command_KILL            :( ('k'|'K') | ( ('k'|'K')('i'|'I')('l'|'L')('l'|'L') ) ); 
Command_NEW             :( ('n'|'N') | ( ('n'|'N')('e'|'E')('w'|'W') ) ); 
Command_SET             :( ('s'|'S') | ( ('s'|'S')('e'|'E')('t'|'T') ) );


INT : [0-9]+;
ID : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
Space: ' ';
Equal: '=';

newCommand
    :   Command_NEW Space ID
    ;
setCommand
    :   Command_SET Space ID Space*  Equal Space* INT
    ;
```

I have a problem, when ID like name as commands (NEW,SET e.t.c.)

Comment: Slightly off topic, since ANTLR 4 support the character class notation, `[...]`, matching `k` case insensitively would be easier like `[kK]` instead of `('k'|'K')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the Wikipedia page, MUMPS doesn't have reserved words:

> Reserved words: None. Since MUMPS interprets source code by context, there is no need for reserved words. You may use the names of language commands as variables.

Lexer rules like `Command_KILL` function exactly like reserved words: they're designed to make sure no other token is generated when input `"kill"` is encountered. So token type `Command_KILL` will always be produced on `"kill"`, even if it's intended to be an identifier. You can keep the command lexer rules if you want, but you'll have to treat them like IDs as well because you just don't know what `"kill"` refers to based on the token alone.

Making a MUMPS implementation in ANTLR means focusing on token usage and context rather than token types. Consider this grammar:

```
grammar Example;


document    : (expr (EOL|EOF))+;
expr        : command=ID Space+ value (Space* COMMA Space* value)*  #CallExpr
            | command=ID Space+ name=ID Space* Equal Space* value   #SetExpr
            ;     

value       : ID | INT;

INT         : [0-9]+;
ID          : [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9]*;
Space       : ' ';
Equal       : '=';
EOL         : [\r\n]+;
COMMA       : ',';
```

Parser rule `expr` knows when an `ID` token is a command based on the layout of the entire line.

- If the input tokens are `ID ID`, then the input is a `CallExpr`: the first `ID` is a command name and the second `ID` is a regular identifier.
- If the input tokens are `ID ID Equal ID`, then the input is a `SetExpr`: the first `ID` will be a command (either `"set"` or something like it), the second `ID` is the target identifier, and the third `ID` is the source identifier.

Here's a Java test application followed by a test case similar to the one mentioned in your question.

```java
import java.util.List;

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.ANTLRInputStream;
import org.antlr.v4.runtime.CommonTokenStream;

public class ExampleTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ANTLRInputStream input = new ANTLRInputStream(
                "new new, set, kill\nset kill = new");

        ExampleLexer lexer = new ExampleLexer(input);

        ExampleParser parser = new ExampleParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        parser.addParseListener(new ExampleBaseListener() {
            @Override
            public void exitCallExpr(ExampleParser.CallExprContext ctx) {
                System.out.println("Call:");
                System.out.printf("\tcommand = %s%n", ctx.command.getText());
                List<ExampleParser.ValueContext> values = ctx.value();
                if (values != null) {
                    for (int i = 0, count = values.size(); i < count; ++i) {
                        ExampleParser.ValueContext value = values.get(i);
                        System.out.printf("\targ[%d]  = %s%n", i,
                                value.getText());
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void exitSetExpr(ExampleParser.SetExprContext ctx) {
                System.out.println("Set:");
                System.out.printf("\tcommand = %s%n", ctx.command.getText());
                System.out.printf("\tname    = %s%n", ctx.name.getText());
                System.out.printf("\tvalue   = %s%n", ctx.value().getText());
            }

        });

        parser.document();
    }
}
```

#### Input

```
new new, set, kill
set kill = new
```

#### Output

```
Call:
    command = new
    arg[0]  = new
    arg[1]  = set
    arg[2]  = kill
Set:
    command = set
    name    = kill
    value   = new
```

It's up to the calling code to determine whether a command is valid in a given context. The parser can't reasonably handle this because of MUMPS's loose approach to commands and identifiers. But it's not as bad as it may sound: you'll know which commands function like a call and which function like a set, so you'll be able to test the input from the `Listener` that ANTLR produces. In the code above, for example, it would be very easy to test whether "set" was the command passed to `exitSetExpr`.

Some MUMPS syntax may be more difficult to process than this, but the general approach will be the same: let the lexer treat commands and identifiers like `ID`s, and use the parser rules to determine whether an `ID` refers to a command or an identifier based on the context of the entire line.